# R Script plots but Rmarkdown doesnt

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to do an exercise in Rmarkdown. I'm trying to do this:

```
regresion <- lm(sbp ~ bmi, data = framingham)
plot(framingham$sbp, framingham$bmi, xlab = "SBP", ylab = "BMI")
abline (regresion)
```

When I execute this chunk, plot does not show inside the Plots Panel of RStudio and then *abline* shows:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

But if I try to execute a plot in a simple R Script in RStudio:

```
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

It appears OK in the Plots Panel.

I'm totally blocked. Could you help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the x and y variables in the plot command, it should be `plot(x,y)` instead of `plot(y,x)`.

Here is a minimum working example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
regression <- lm(qsec ~ hp, data = mtcars)
plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$qsec, xlab = "horsepower", ylab = "1/4 mile time")
abline(regression)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing

```
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
```

You should test

```
plot(framingham$sbp, framingham$bmi, xlab = "SBP", ylab = "BMI")
```

to see whether this plots normally. Most likely your problem is here -- perhaps `framingham` is not a dataframe, or something like that.